# Inheritance OR Call the function from another function in R

Tags: r, function, api, inheritance, plumber

I am Developing an API for that I am using Plumber were I have created function and wanted to call the function into another function. Suppose First Function can be called by Second Function or Second function can be function be third function.

```
library(plumber)

#* @get /echo
trial_query<- function(msg = "") {
    list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}

#* @get /calling
abc <- function(){
  list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}
```

User-input is store in msg variable and I want call the trail_query function and also with there is argument in abc function

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. I would advise to read on [R scoping](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/scoping-rules-of-r.html).

Here is something that could inspire you, maybe?

```r
library(plumber)

states <- new.env()
trial_query<- function(msg = "") {
    states$msg <- msg
    list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}

abc <- function(){
  list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", states$msg, "'"))
}

#* @get /echo
trial_query

#* @get /calling
abc
```

Comment: I don’t think this is good advice. There should be a *very* good reason to depend on global state. It’s almost certainly not required (nor a good solution) here.

Comment: Better with an env?

Comment: Not really, this is still effectively a global variable, just with more letters. I know too little about ‘plumber’ to know whether maintaining global state is really necessary. But in most other cases this would definitely *not* be required. — One way to avoid global state would be the use of a closure.

Comment: A closure isn't just another form of environment? This env is scoped to this particular plumber router. Each router has its own environment where it stores these.

Comment: A closure is an environment, but it isn’t *public*, it’s only accessible to whoever holds it. Of course creating a closure in the global environment would be no better than creating an environment/variable directly. — But like I said, I don’t know ‘plumber’. If you think that this kind of state sharing is acceptable here then that’s good enough for me.

Comment: No, I do not like it because there is no guaranteed that the state will be maintained from one call to another as plumber use a lot of futures/promises. I will wait for more explanation from @Aman Vishwakarma to provide a more tailored answer.

Comment: @BrunoTremblay I just want to use function one to run function two and also thank you for your response.

Comment: @BrunoTremblay what does the $ between states and msg indicates

Comment: Read the documentation on ?base::Extract, it access an element in another by name.